# HTML glitch: adsense ads randomly displaying with no ad code

Tags: html, adsense

For some reason in all of my articles on my site have Adsense ads within the articles and there is no ad code I put displaying the ads within the articles HTML text section. Is this just an HTML glitch? Is there a WordPress method to get rid of the ads in the articles?

If you even inspect element the ads within the article it shows ad code of the ad but when you go to the same spot where the code was in the view source there is nothing there. [site](http://www.ledgetechs.com)

This is the code I see in inspect element

```html
<ins data-ad-format="auto" class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9148904539085381" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" style="display: block; margin: auto; background-color: transparent;"><ins id="aswift_2_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:150px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:600px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:150px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:600px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe width="600" height="150" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:600px;height:150px;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
```

But in the view source, this code is not here. How can I get rid of these ads? I am using WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WordPress. Try advanced ads, it's free plugin. It is the best way to inject ads and disable ads on posts or pages you don't want ads to show up. All the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the AdSense's Auto Ads setting is acting up. 
Auto Ads mode is supposed to let AdSense choose where to place the ads automatically and let the "machine learning" figure out which placements perform the best. 
Auto Ads can display ad units without you consciously inserting a code.

You can turn off Auto Ads all together within Ad Sense settings.

-Log in to AdSense

-Click "Ads" and then "Auto Ads"

-Select "Global Settings

-Uncheck all the auto ads options

-"Save" the settings

See below link for more details.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9214966